# How to get parent element by selector

Tags: javascript, dom

Example:

```html
<div someAttr="parentDiv. We need to get it from child.">
    <table>
        ...
        <td> <div id="myDiv"></div> </td>
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

I want to get the parent by some selector from the inner div element (the one with the `myDiv` class).

How do I achieve that with plain JavaScript, **without jQuery**?

Something like:

```js
var div = document.getElementById('myDiv');
div.someParentFindMethod('some selector');
```

Comment: Google give only jQuery.parent everywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the closest ancestor element that has a specific class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119673/find-the-closest-ancestor-element-that-has-a-specific-class)

Comment: Please update selected answer per suggestion from @soullivaneuh below.

Comment: Jquery closest for people who don't have the constraint of not using JQuery - https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: Note that this question is looking for **ancestor** elements matching a query; for anyone looking for only the **parent** element, try `element.parentNode` or if it needs to match a query, something like `element.parentNode.matches('.some-query') ? element.parentNode : null`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Here's the most basic version:

```
function collectionHas(a, b) { //helper function (see below)
    for(var i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i ++) {
        if(a[i] == b) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
function findParentBySelector(elm, selector) {
    var all = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    var cur = elm.parentNode;
    while(cur && !collectionHas(all, cur)) { //keep going up until you find a match
        cur = cur.parentNode; //go up
    }
    return cur; //will return null if not found
}

var yourElm = document.getElementById("yourElm"); //div in your original code
var selector = ".yes";
var parent = findParentBySelector(yourElm, selector);
```

Comment: This is rather inefficient in that it retrieves all elements with that selector in the entire document, rather than just checking the parent.

Comment: This [JSPerf test](https://jsperf.com/matches-vs-closest) analyzes `Element.matches()`, `Element.closest()`, and one polyfill for each of those methods. The polyfill for `Element.matches()` looks very similar to your implementation. To address the performance concern of @user663031, perhaps you could use `Element.matches()` instead of `Document.querySelectorAll()`. It appears to run faster than the related polyfill.

Answer (score 377):

You may use [`closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) in modern browsers:

```
var div = document.querySelector('div#myDiv');
div.closest('div[someAtrr]');
```

Use object detection to supply a [polyfill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill_(programming)) or alternative method for backwards compatability with IE.

Comment: Just include this polyfill: https://github.com/jonathantneal/closest. Also available on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/element-closest.

Answer (score 44):

Finds the closest parent (or the element itself) that matches the given selector. Also included is a selector to stop searching, in case you know a common ancestor that you should stop searching at.

```
function closest(el, selector, stopSelector) {
  var retval = null;
  while (el) {
    if (el.matches(selector)) {
      retval = el;
      break
    } else if (stopSelector && el.matches(stopSelector)) {
      break
    }
    el = el.parentElement;
  }
  return retval;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

By using **querySelector()** and **closest()** methods is possible to get the parent element.

- `querySelector()` returns the first element that match a
  specified CSS selector(s) in the document.
- `closest()` searches up the DOM tree for the closest element
  which matches a specified CSS selector.

### Usage example

```js
const element = document.querySelector('td')

console.log(element.closest('div'))
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

In case of needing to select more than one element, **querySelectorAll()** is a good fit.

- `querySelectorAll()` returns all elements in the document that match a specified CSS selector(s), as a static NodeList object.

To select the desired element, is necessary to specify it inside `[]` so, for example for the second element would be: `element[1]`

In the following example `closest()` method is used to get the parent `<tr>` element of an specific selected element.

```js
const el = document.querySelectorAll('td')

console.log(el[1].closest('tr'))
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr id="1">
      <td> First text </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
      <td> Second text </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

### Using leech's answer with indexOf (to support IE)

This is using what leech talked about, but making it work for IE (IE doesn't support matches):

```
function closest(el, selector, stopSelector) {
  var retval = null;
  while (el) {
    if (el.className.indexOf(selector) > -1) {
      retval = el;
      break
    } else if (stopSelector && el.className.indexOf(stopSelector) > -1) {
      break
    }
    el = el.parentElement;
  }
  return retval;
}
```

It's not perfect, but it works if the selector is unique enough so it won't accidentally match the incorrect element.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a recursive solution:

```
function closest(el, selector, stopSelector) {
  if(!el || !el.parentElement) return null
  else if(stopSelector && el.parentElement.matches(stopSelector)) return null
  else if(el.parentElement.matches(selector)) return el.parentElement
  else return closest(el.parentElement, selector, stopSelector)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I thought I would provide a much more robust example, also in typescript, but it would be easy to convert to pure javascript. This function will query parents using either the ID like so "#my-element" or the class ".my-class" and unlike some of these answers will handle multiple classes. I found I named some similarly and so the examples above were finding the wrong things.

```
function queryParentElement(el:HTMLElement | null, selector:string) {
    let isIDSelector = selector.indexOf("#") === 0
    if (selector.indexOf('.') === 0 || selector.indexOf('#') === 0) {
        selector = selector.slice(1)
    }
    while (el) {
        if (isIDSelector) {
            if (el.id === selector) {
                return el
            }
        }
        else if (el.classList.contains(selector)) {
            return el;
        }
        el = el.parentElement;
    }
    return null;
}
```

#### To select by class name:

`let elementByClassName = queryParentElement(someElement,".my-class")`

#### To select by ID:

`let elementByID = queryParentElement(someElement,"#my-element")`

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple way using recursion to get the parent with a specific class. You can modify it to switch depending on the selector, but the principle is the same:

```js
function findParentByClass(child, parentClass) {
    let parent = child.parentElement;

    while(!(parent.className === parentClass)){
        parent = findParentByClass(child.parentElement, parentClass)
    }

    return parent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simple example of a function parent_by_selector which return a parent or null (no selector matches):

```
function parent_by_selector(node, selector, stop_selector = 'body') {
  var parent = node.parentNode;
  while (true) {
    if (parent.matches(stop_selector)) break;
    if (parent.matches(selector)) break;
    parent = parent.parentNode; // get upper parent and check again
  }
  if (parent.matches(stop_selector)) parent = null; // when parent is a tag 'body' -> parent not found
  return parent;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  /* --------------------------------------------------
    get a parent element by its id or classname

    [child] - the element were starting with
    [idOrClassName] - id or classname of parent element
                      were looking for
    ------------------------------------------------- */
 function getParent(child, idOrClassName = ""){

    while(child.tagName.toLowerCase() != "body"){
  
       // get the next parent up
      child = child.parentNode;
 
       // we reached body tag which means parent element with
       // class or id of [idOrClassName] not found so exit
      if(child.tagName.toLowerCase() == "body"){
         return false;
      }

       // if the id of this element = [idOrClassName] or .classList
       // of [child] contains [idOrClassName], weve found our element
      if((child.id == idOrClassName) || (child.classList.contains(idOrClassName))){
         return child;
      }
   }

 }
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is simple way to access parent id

```
document.getElementById("child1").parentNode;
```

will do the magic for you to access the parent div.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body id="body">
<script>
function alertAncestorsUntilID() {
var a = document.getElementById("child").parentNode;
alert(a.id);
}
</script>
<div id="master">
Master
<div id="child">Child</div>
</div>
<script>
alertAncestorsUntilID();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: He wants the parent **with some class**, not just the parent.

Comment: @torazaburo This is Question from OP "JavaScript: How to get parent element by selector?" it does not mention Class

Comment: Selector could also be a class or attribute and so on

Answer (score -4):

```
var base_element = document.getElementById('__EXAMPLE_ELEMENT__');
for( var found_parent=base_element, i=100; found_parent.parentNode && !(found_parent=found_parent.parentNode).classList.contains('__CLASS_NAME__') && i>0; i-- );
console.log( found_parent );
```