# Find the closest ancestor element that has a specific class

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How can I find an element's ancestor that is closest up the tree that has a particular class, **in pure JavaScript**? For example, in a tree like so:

```
<div class="far ancestor">
    <div class="near ancestor">
        <p>Where am I?</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I want `div.near.ancestor` if I try this on the `p` and search for `ancestor`.

Comment: please note that the outer div is not a parent, it's an *ancestor* to the `p` element. If you actually only want to get the parent node, you can do `ele.parentNode`.

Comment: @FelixKling: Didn't know that terminology; I will change it.

Comment: It's actually the same as we humans use :) The father (parent) of your father (parent) is not your father (parent), it's your grandfather (grandparent), or more generally speaking, your ancestor.

Answer (score 622, accepted):

Update: Now supported [in most major browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=closest)

```
document.querySelector("p").closest(".near.ancestor")
```

Note that this can match selectors, not just classes

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.closest

---

For legacy browsers that do not support `closest()` but have `matches()` one can build selector-matching similar to @rvighne's class matching:

```
function findAncestor (el, sel) {
    while ((el = el.parentElement) && !((el.matches || el.matchesSelector).call(el,sel)));
    return el;
}
```

Comment: Still not supported in the current versions of Internet Explorer, Edge and Opera Mini.

Comment: @kleinfreund - still not supported in IE, Edge, or Opera mini. http://caniuse.com/#search=closest

Comment: `document` has no `matches` (nor `matchesSelector`) so this polyfill is incorrect. Also, what's with code golfing?

Comment: Also, `(el.matches || el.matchesSelector)(sel)` throws `Illegal invocation` in Chrome.

Comment: @KonradDzwinel, that's odd because `parentElement` should only return objects implementing the Element interface and `matches` is defined on the Element interface. So according to specs the there should never be a case where the method is not available on el when it's invoked. But the second issue you raise is valid.

Comment: June 2016: Looks like all browsers still havn't caught up

Comment: Use polyfill from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) to get `matches` support

Comment: There is a [DOM Level 4](https://github.com/WebReflection/dom4) polyfill with `closest` plus many more advanced DOM traversal features. You can pull that implementation on its own or include the whole bundle to get a lot of new features in your code.

Comment: Edge 15 has support, that should cover all major browsers. Unless you count IE11, but that doesn't receive any updates

Comment: polyfill https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js from https://polyfill.io/v2/docs/, this polyfill can cover all major browsers. The size of polyfill is 0 bytes if called from Chrome browser.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest has a polyfill as well.

Answer (score 209):

This does the trick:

```
function findAncestor (el, cls) {
    while ((el = el.parentElement) && !el.classList.contains(cls));
    return el;
}
```

The while loop waits until `el` has the desired class, and it sets `el` to `el`'s parent every iteration so in the end, you have the ancestor with that class or `null`.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8RfbT/69/), if anyone wants to improve it. It won't work on old browsers (i.e. IE); see this [compatibility table for classList](http://beta.caniuse.com/#feat=classlist). `parentElement` is used here because `parentNode` would involve more work to make sure that the node is an element.

Comment: For an alternative to `.classList`, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/5898656/218196.

Comment: I fixed the code, but it would still throw an error if there is no ancestor with such a class name.

Comment: @FelixKling: Could you please explain why `parentElement` was wrong?

Comment: Uh, I thought it didn't exist, [but I was wrong](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.parentElement). Anyways, `parentElement` is a rather new property (DOM level 4) and `parentNode` exists since... forever. So `parentNode` also works in older browsers, whereas `parentElement` might not. Of course you could make the same argument for/against `classList`, but it doesn't have a simple alternative, like `parentElement` has. I actually wonder why `parentElement` exists at all, it doesn't seem to add any value over `parentNode`.

Comment: @FelixKling: For example, parentElement will return `null` for parent of the root element, but parentNode will return the `document`.

Comment: @FelixKling: Just edited, it now works fine for the case when no such ancestor exists. I must have gotten overeager with the short original version.

Comment: [className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.className) is an alternate for classList.

Comment: If you wanted to do it in one expression, you could do `while ((el = el.parentNode) && !el.classList.contains(cls));`. But at some point it becomes less readable.

Comment: @FelixKling: That won't work because eventually you might get to `document`, and the document object has no `classList`. Perhaps I should revert it to use `parentElement` again? Browser support isn't too bad.

Comment: Ah right... damn it. Yeah, use `parentElement` in that case, sorry for messing around with your answer. Just make sure to include a link to the MDN documentation, because I'd assume that people rather know `parentNode` than `parentElement`.

Comment: If you want to check for the class name in the parameter element itself, before searching its ancestors, you can simply switch the order of the conditions in the loop: `while (!el.classList.contains(cls) && (el = el.parentElement));`

Comment: @Nicomak - Thanks for this heads up.  And to be a little more specific, it would be more accurate to say "in addition to searching its ancestors" instead of "before searching its ancestors".  The code as-is will *never* consider the classes of the original `el` element.

Answer (score 80):

Use ***element.closest()***

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

See this example DOM:

```
<article>
  <div id="div-01">Here is div-01
    <div id="div-02">Here is div-02
      <div id="div-03">Here is div-03</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

This is how you would use element.closest:

```
var el = document.getElementById('div-03');

var r1 = el.closest("#div-02");  
// returns the element with the id=div-02

var r2 = el.closest("div div");  
// returns the closest ancestor which is a div in div, here is div-03 itself

var r3 = el.closest("article > div");  
// returns the closest ancestor which is a div and has a parent article, here is div-01

var r4 = el.closest(":not(div)");
// returns the closest ancestor which is not a div, here is the outmost article
```

Comment: I see that all browsers except Internet explorer now support 'closest' (June 2020).

Comment: What for closest div but not itself?

Comment: @ShashwatKumar Good question brother.

Comment: @ShashwatKumar, closest includes the element itself, so if you want to find the closest div (from the parent elements) you can start searching from the parent. 

Something like: el.parentNode.closest('div');

It is JavaScript and it should work for all browsers except IE.

Comment: I had fetched inputs (type button) in a form using a for(item of elementsOfClassNameX), and with those "items" I could not use closest()

Answer (score 18):

Based on the [the8472 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27037567/171991) and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches here is cross-platform 2017 solution:

```
if (!Element.prototype.matches) {
    Element.prototype.matches =
        Element.prototype.matchesSelector ||
        Element.prototype.mozMatchesSelector ||
        Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector ||
        Element.prototype.oMatchesSelector ||
        Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector ||
        function(s) {
            var matches = (this.document || this.ownerDocument).querySelectorAll(s),
                i = matches.length;
            while (--i >= 0 && matches.item(i) !== this) {}
            return i > -1;
        };
}

function findAncestor(el, sel) {
    if (typeof el.closest === 'function') {
        return el.closest(sel) || null;
    }
    while (el) {
        if (el.matches(sel)) {
            return el;
        }
        el = el.parentElement;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

@rvighne solution works well, but as identified in the comments `ParentElement` and `ClassList` both have compatibility issues. To make it more compatible, I have used:

```
function findAncestor (el, cls) {
    while ((el = el.parentNode) && el.className.indexOf(cls) < 0);
    return el;
}
```

- `parentNode` property instead of the `parentElement` property
- `indexOf` method on the `className` property instead of the `contains` method on the `classList` property.

Of course, indexOf is simply looking for the presence of that string, it does not care if it is the whole string or not. So if you had another element with class 'ancestor-type' it would still return as having found 'ancestor', if this is a problem for you, perhaps you can use regexp to find an exact match.

Answer (score 7):

This solution should work for IE9 and up.

It's like jQuery's parents() method when you need to get a parent container which might be up a few levels from the given element, like finding the containing `<form>` of a clicked `<button>`. Looks through the parents until the matching selector is found, or until it reaches the `<body>`. Returns either the matching element or the `<body>`.

```
function parents(el, selector){
    var parent_container = el;
    do {
        parent_container = parent_container.parentNode;
    }
    while( !parent_container.matches(selector) && parent_container !== document.body );

    return parent_container;
}
```