# JavaScript Function Working on Chrome but not IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have code below for a couple of info boxes I have created along with some help from other coders, using HTML CSS and JavaScript. My info boxes are supposed to show another div when hovered on and maintain in focus until you click a button that closes the hover div. Everything works perfectly on Google Chrome, but the JavaScript hover functions don't seem to be working on IE. Does anyone have any ideas on how to make the code work in IE. Anything helps, cheers!

```js
function open(e){
  let li = e.target;
  li.classList.add('hover');
}

function close(e){
  const hoverable = e.target.closest('li.hover');
  hoverable.classList.remove('hover');
}

const infoBoxListItems = document.querySelectorAll('.info-boxes li');
const closeButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.profileclose');

infoBoxListItems.forEach(li => {
  li.addEventListener('mouseenter', open);
});

closeButtons.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', close);
});
```

```css
.everything {
  text-align:center;
height:1000px;
}

.everything.hover {
cursor: default;
}

#wrapper {

    margin: 0 auto;
}
#wrapper img{
    width:100%;       /* the image will now scale down as its parent gets smaller */
}

.infobox-list {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

ul, ol, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style-type: none;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ul, li, ol, form, fieldset {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul, menu, dir {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: disc;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
}

.hr {
  border-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  margin-left:9px;
  width: 210px;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    color: #555;
    min-width: 20em;
}

.info-boxes li {
  width: 310px;
    height: 535px;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    border: 0px solid #efefef;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 0 0px 0px;
    cursor:pointer;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: scale(0.75); 
}

.ptext
{
  text-align:center;
  font-size:20px;

}

.profile
{
  margin-top:10%;
  margin-left:1px;
  width:75px;
  height:75px;
}

.performance
{
  margin-left:1px;
  margin-top:10%;
  width:75px;
  height:75px;
}

.learning
{
  margin-top:10%;
  width:75px;
  height:75px;
}

.team
{
  margin-top:10%;
  width:75px;
  height:75px;
}

.smallicons
{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}

.profileclose {
margin-top:215px;
}

.infobox-list li {
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight:lighter;
}

.info-boxes li .infobox {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 535px;
  width: 310px;
}

.info-boxes li .infobox:before { 
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  width: 160%; 
  height: 188%; 
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); /* fallback */
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(46deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(46deg);
  transform: rotate(30deg);
} 

.info-boxes li.hover .shade {
  animation-name: windowshade;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.info-boxes li .shade,
.info-boxes li.hover .shade {
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

section p {
  line-height: 1.3em;
  color: #6d6e71;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  text-align:left;
}

p {
  display: block;
}

.info-boxes li .shade {
  position: absolute;
  width: 310px;
  height: 555px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #6caf46;
  color: #fff;
  display: table;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 20px 10px 0;
  transform: translateY(-340px);
  animation-name: windowshade-out;
}

.info-boxes li .shade h3 {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bold
}

.info-boxes li .shade p {
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 3em;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.ie9 .info-boxes li.hover .shade {
  top: 245px
}

.info-boxes li.hover a {
  text-decoration: none
}

@keyframes windowshade {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-535px)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0)
  }
}

@keyframes windowshade-out {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-535px)
  }
}
```

```html
  <section class="info-boxes">
    <ul class="infobox-list">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="infobox">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <img class="profile" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497637065/profile_i0evlz.png"></tr>
              <tr>
                <p class="ptext">Profile</p>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="shade">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497301295/About-Me_dudglr.png">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <p>About Me</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/Resume_tb7t02.png"> </td>
                  <td>
                    <p>Resume</p>
                    <hr class="hr">
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497280574/Accountabilities_qfdcns.png"> </td>
                  <td>
                    <p>Accountabilities
                      <p/>
                      <hr class="hr">
                  </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <div class="profileclose">Close</div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="infobox">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <img class="learning" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497637065/Learning-Icon_hqtc2k.png"></tr>
            <tr>
              <p class="ptext">Learning</p>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="shade">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497297687/Training-Plan_v43ne7.png">
              </td>
              <td>
                <p>Training Plan</p>
                <hr class="hr">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497297687/Training-History_czttv1.png"> </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Training History</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497298863/coursefeedback_qdh1wm.png"> </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Course Feedback</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497299106/Favourites_y9gkce.png"> </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Training Favourites
                    <p/>
                    <hr class="hr">
                </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="infobox">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <img class="performance" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497637065/Performance-Icon_ozaldt.png"></tr>
              <tr>
                <p class="ptext">Performance</p>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="shade">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/Goals_aw4nso.png">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Goals</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284934/EA_n8lvj1.png" </td>
                  <td>
                    <p>Effectiveness Assessment</p>
                    <hr class="hr">
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/development_yfv6o1.png" </td>
                  <td>
                    <p>Development Plan</p>
                    <hr class="hr">
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497285433/resources_b3r88g.png"> </td>
                  <td>
                    <p>Resources
                      <p/>
                      <hr class="hr">
                  </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <div class="infobox">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <img class="team" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497637065/team_nl2cwh.png"></tr>
            <tr>
              <p class="ptext">Team</p>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="shade">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497300652/Team_iovnl5.png">
              </td>
              <td>
                <p>Team</p>
                <hr class="hr">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/Goals_aw4nso.png"> </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Team Goals</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/development_yfv6o1.png"> </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Team Development</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497297687/Training-Plan_v43ne7.png"> </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Team Training</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497301295/Approval_f9y1da.png"> </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Approvals
                    <p/>
                    <hr class="hr">
                </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: What version of IE are you testing with? IE 8.0 and lower did not support addEventListener.  You have to use attachEvent.

Comment: Caniuse [classList](http://caniuse.com/#search=classList)?

Comment: @DavidP using IE 11

Comment: It looks like your JS is a little advanced for IE11, [**arrow functions**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions) and [**closest()**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=element-closest) are not support ES6 features. Looks like you'll have to [transpile](https://babeljs.io/repl/) your code from ES6 to ES5 if you want to continue coding ES6 or use ES5. IE also appears to be more strict on the use of `forEach()`, `querySelectorAll()` returns a `NodeList` (Object) and not an array.

Comment: @DimaSan it's not simply the use of classList. There's multiple issues; ES6, DOM API etc. that are preventing the code from working in IE11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code is a little advanced for IE11 along with some variances in browser implementation.

For arrow functions and some other ES6 features not supported in IE11 you can use a [transpiler](https://babeljs.io/repl/) to transform your JS from ES6 to ES5. Though this will not resolve all issues. The transpiler will not transpile `target.closest()`. You will need to find a different implementation of [searching ancestor elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119673/find-the-closest-ancestor-element-that-has-a-specific-class#22119674).

IE11 won't let you use `forEach()` with a *NodeList*, an *Object*, which is what `document.querySelectorAll()` returns. You can use `[].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll() )`, or similar method, to convert the *NodeList* to an array. Once the collection is an array `forEach()` will work as expected in IE11.

```js
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119673/find-the-closest-ancestor-element-that-has-a-specific-class#22119674
function findAncestor(el, cls) {
  while ((el = el.parentElement) && !el.classList.contains(cls));
  return el;
}

function open(e) {
  let li = e.target;
  li.classList.add('hover');
}

function close(e) {
  const hoverable = findAncestor(e.target, 'hover');
  hoverable.classList.remove('hover');
}

const infoBoxListItems = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.info-boxes li'));
const closeButtons = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.profileclose'));

infoBoxListItems.forEach(function(li) {
  li.addEventListener('mouseenter', open);
});

closeButtons.forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', close);
});
```

```css
.everything {
  text-align: center;
  height: 1000px;
}

.everything.hover {
  cursor: default;
}

#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
  /* the image will now scale down as its parent gets smaller */
}

.infobox-list {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

ul,
ol,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-position: outside;
  list-style-type: none;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
ul,
li,
ol,
form,
fieldset {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul,
menu,
dir {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: disc;
  -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
}

.hr {
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  margin-left: 9px;
  width: 210px;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  color: #555;
  min-width: 20em;
}

.info-boxes li {
  width: 310px;
  height: 535px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border: 0px solid #efefef;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0 0px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: scale(0.75);
}

.ptext {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.profile {
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 1px;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
}

.performance {
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-top: 10%;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
}

.learning {
  margin-top: 10%;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
}

.team {
  margin-top: 10%;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
}

.smallicons {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.profileclose {
  margin-top: 215px;
}

.infobox-list li {
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.info-boxes li .infobox {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 535px;
  width: 310px;
}

.info-boxes li .infobox:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  width: 160%;
  height: 188%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  /* fallback */
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(46deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(46deg);
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.info-boxes li.hover .shade {
  animation-name: windowshade;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.info-boxes li .shade,
.info-boxes li.hover .shade {
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

section p {
  line-height: 1.3em;
  color: #6d6e71;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  text-align: left;
}

p {
  display: block;
}

.info-boxes li .shade {
  position: absolute;
  width: 310px;
  height: 555px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #6caf46;
  color: #fff;
  display: table;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 20px 10px 0;
  transform: translateY(-340px);
  animation-name: windowshade-out;
}

.info-boxes li .shade h3 {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bold
}

.info-boxes li .shade p {
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 3em;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.ie9 .info-boxes li.hover .shade {
  top: 245px
}

.info-boxes li.hover a {
  text-decoration: none
}

@keyframes windowshade {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-535px)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0)
  }
}

@keyframes windowshade-out {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-535px)
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="info-boxes">
  <ul class="infobox-list">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="infobox">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <img class="profile" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497637065/profile_i0evlz.png"></tr>
            <tr>
              <p class="ptext">Profile</p>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="shade">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497301295/About-Me_dudglr.png">
              </td>
              <td>
                <p>About Me</p>
                <hr class="hr">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/Resume_tb7t02.png"> </td>
              <td>
                <p>Resume</p>
                <hr class="hr">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497280574/Accountabilities_qfdcns.png"> </td>
              <td>
                <p>Accountabilities
                  <p/>
                  <hr class="hr">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <div class="profileclose">Close</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="infobox">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <img class="learning" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497637065/Learning-Icon_hqtc2k.png"></tr>
          <tr>
            <p class="ptext">Learning</p>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="shade">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497297687/Training-Plan_v43ne7.png">
            </td>
            <td>
              <p>Training Plan</p>
              <hr class="hr">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497297687/Training-History_czttv1.png"> </td>
            <td>
              <p>Training History</p>
              <hr class="hr">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497298863/coursefeedback_qdh1wm.png"> </td>
            <td>
              <p>Course Feedback</p>
              <hr class="hr">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497299106/Favourites_y9gkce.png"> </td>
            <td>
              <p>Training Favourites
                <p/>
                <hr class="hr">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="infobox">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <img class="performance" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497637065/Performance-Icon_ozaldt.png"></tr>
            <tr>
              <p class="ptext">Performance</p>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="shade">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/Goals_aw4nso.png">
              </td>
              <td>
                <p>Goals</p>
                <hr class="hr">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284934/EA_n8lvj1.png" </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Effectiveness Assessment</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/development_yfv6o1.png" </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Development Plan</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497285433/resources_b3r88g.png"> </td>
              <td>
                <p>Resources
                  <p/>
                  <hr class="hr">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="infobox">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <img class="team" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497637065/team_nl2cwh.png"></tr>
          <tr>
            <p class="ptext">Team</p>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="shade">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497300652/Team_iovnl5.png">
            </td>
            <td>
              <p>Team</p>
              <hr class="hr">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/Goals_aw4nso.png"> </td>
            <td>
              <p>Team Goals</p>
              <hr class="hr">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/development_yfv6o1.png"> </td>
            <td>
              <p>Team Development</p>
              <hr class="hr">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497297687/Training-Plan_v43ne7.png"> </td>
            <td>
              <p>Team Training</p>
              <hr class="hr">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497301295/Approval_f9y1da.png"> </td>
            <td>
              <p>Approvals
                <p/>
                <hr class="hr">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>

    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is compile your javascript with [babel](http://babeljs.io/). It will output the following code, which works in current browsers:

```js
'use strict';

function open(e) {
  var li = e.target;
  li.classList.add('hover');
}

function close(e) {
  var hoverable = e.target.closest('li.hover');
  hoverable.classList.remove('hover');
}

var infoBoxListItems = document.querySelectorAll('.info-boxes li');
var closeButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.profileclose');

infoBoxListItems.forEach(function (li) {
  li.addEventListener('mouseenter', open);
});

closeButtons.forEach(function (btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', close);
});
```

To take it one step further and add support IE9 and below, replace

`li.classList.add('hover');` with
`li.className += " hover"`

and

`hoverable.classList.remove('hover')` with
`hoverable.className = hoverable.className.replace('hover', '');`

Comment: @ColeGwozdecki. it really should. What I posted is `ES2015 - strict` Are you sure you're not running IE in "compatibility mode"? Any errors in your console? Do you have other scripts in page? Where and when are you running this script?

Comment: Is this supposed to work, or did I miss something in my code? https://codepen.io/ColeGwoz/pen/weJyVm?editors=0110

Comment: @Cole, I'm currently on a Linux machine without possibility to test IE native. But, as you can see [here](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) IE11 should not have any trouble with ES2015 - strict. Could you further detail what you mean by "not working"?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu the two issues I see are 1) `forEach()` in IE11 isn't supported for a _NodeList_ objects and 2) the [`closest()`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=element-closest) method for an _Element_ is not supported.