# Elegant way of checking if one of the parentNodes has a certain class

Tags: javascript, html

I have a menu that expands and retracts on hover. The problem is the menu has many elements and to trigger my expand function I need to write something like below. My actual code includes more code and I was wondering if there would be a better way to do this.

```
var e = event.target

if(
e.parentNode.className.split(" ")[0] === "main-section" ||
e.parentNode.parentNode.className.split(" ")[0] === "main-section" ||
e.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className.split(" ")[0] === "main-section"){
//do somehtings}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In modern environments you can use the DOM's [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method:

```
if (e.closest(".main-section")) {
    // One was found...
}
```

It looks at the current element to see if it matches the selector, then its parent element, then *its* parent, etc. to the root of the tree. It returns the element it finds, or `null` if it doesn't find one.

For slightly older environments, `Element#closest` can be polyfilled. Or if you don't like polyfilling, you can give yourself a utility function instead that uses `closest` if it exists, or uses [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) if not:

```
function closest(el, selector) {
    if (el.closest) {
        return el.closest(selector);
    }
    var matches = el.matches || el.matchesSelector;
    while (el) {
        if (matches.call(el, selector)) {
            return el;
        }
        el = el.parentNode;
    }
    return null;
}
```

...which you'd use like this:

```
if (closest(e, ".main-section")) {
    // One was found...
}
```

Comment: This is so much better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Method `closest()` is not supported in some browsers, so I took this function for you from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27037567/7545390)

```
function findAncestor (el, sel) {
    while ((el = el.parentElement) && !((el.matches || el.matchesSelector).call(el,sel)));
    return el;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) with a recursive function like so.

```js
const start = document.getElementById("start");

function recursiveCheck(ele, className, limit = 3, current = 0){
   return ele.classList.contains(className) ? true : current >= limit ? false : recursiveCheck(ele.parentNode, className, limit, current + 1);
}

console.log(
  recursiveCheck(start, "test")
);
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div>
    <div id="start"><div>
  </div>
</div>
```