# How do I detect class of parent element/component

Tags: angular, typescript

I want the contents of an Angular component to change when a certain class exists in one of the parent components/elements. Very similar to the `:host-context()` CSS selector, but in the TypeScript component code.

Using `:host-context(.the-class)`, I can control the visibility of elements in my component, but this will only modify the style of the component. I also want to modify the behavior.

I have also tried the JQuery route with `$(this.element.nativeElement).parents().hasClass("the-class");`. This works reasonably well, but I would prefer a more declarative/Angular approach.

```js
@Component({
  template: `
    <p>{{text}}</p>
  `,
  styles: [`
    :host-context(.the-class) p {
      color: red;
    }
  `]
})
class MyComponent {
  text: string;

  /*
    Change content of 'text' if 'the-class' can be found
    in any of the parents here somewhere.
  */
}
```

So... What is the best way to do this "the Angular way", without resorting to JQuery or native DOM selectors? I realize that this may not be a common use-case, as it would break component isolation and so on. But I figured since the `:host-context` selector exists for styling, there must be something similar for the controller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the closest ancestor element that has a specific class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119673/find-the-closest-ancestor-element-that-has-a-specific-class)

Answer (score 0):

may you can read your parent style-sheet in child component you it will be easy for you to find out the class.

For Exp;

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.scss', '../parent.component.scss']
})
```

here in style URL angular allow to add more than one style sheet so may you can add your parent styles here and then may you can use js method to findout class `document.getElementsByClassName(names);`

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that quite well in Angular.

First of all you can declare a variable to get the class in question like

```
const classname = document.querySelector('the-class') as HTMLElement;
let container = classname.parentNode;
console.log(container)  // You can console log this to see the parent class for yourself
```

With that you should be able to do whatever you want.

Assuming your class is an input or any element related to it you can also do stuffs like this in your Angular component

```
const classname = document.querySelector('the-class') as HTMLElement;
classname.onClick = () => {
let container = classname.parentNode;
console.log(container)  // You can console log this to see the parent class
let container = classname.parentNode;    
}
```