# Dropdown menu closing problem - Javascript / Css / Html

Tags: javascript, events, drop-down-menu, click

Is there a problem if i set same `event handler` and `functionality` on different elements?

I am trying to show a `dropdown menu` and when i click outside of it it should close, which approach is better? Because even when i select items inside the dropdown menu it still closes.

I don't know how to close the dropdown when i click outside so i tried to put both on `header` and `body`. But my result is something messy in the `if statement`.

I need to select for each element in the dropdown to `be strict equal` with the `parentNode` element.

E.g:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu">
 <ul>
  <li>Some link</li>
  <li>Some link</li>
  <li>Some link</li>
  <li>Some link</li>
 </ul>

  <ul>
   <li>Some link</li>
   <li>Some link</li>
   <li>Some link</li>
   <li>Some link</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When i click on a `link` or the `ul` it closes. I want only if i click outside of the `dropdown menu`

```
// Show dropdown more menu
 document.body.addEventListener('click', showMoreMenu);
 ui.header.addEventListener('click', showMoreMenu);

// Show dropdown more menu
function showMoreMenu(e) {
    ui.showMoreMenu(e);

    e.stopPropagation();
}

// Class method
showMoreMenu(e) {
    if(e.target === this.more_btn || e.target.parentElement === this.more_btn || e.target.parentNode === this.more_dropdown_menu || e.target === this.more_dropdown_menu || e.target.parentNode.parentElement === this.more_dropdown_menu) {
            this.more_dropdown_menu.classList.add('visible');
    } else {
        this.more_dropdown_menu.classList.remove('visible');
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery? Cause with jQuery it is way simpler than pure Javascript

Comment: Nop, i want to use pure JS. Any idea??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem i just need it to add the `.closest(selector)` method.

Here you have [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=closest), and here i found a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119673/find-the-closest-ancestor-element-that-has-a-specific-class).

```
hideMenu(e) {
 if(!e.target.closest('.more-dropdown-menu')) {
  this.dropdown_menu.classList.remove('visible')
 }
}

window.addEventListener('click', eventOperations);

function eventOperations(e) {
 ui.hideMenu(e);

 e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

```
document.querySelector("body:not(.dropdown-menu)").addEventListener("click", showMoreMenu);
```

Comment: Hmm let me test it and i will come with a feedback :)