# JavaScript addEventListener on multiple element with event delegation

Tags: javascript, html, css, event-delegation

I want to use `addEventListener` on multiple element with event delegation.

What I want is add click event to `.node` including dynamic element.

I've tried code below, but `target` is different when I click `.title`, `.image`, or `.subtitle`.

So is there any way to get `.node` element ignoring hierarchy?

Thanks in advance :)

```js
document.querySelector(".nodes").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  var target = e.target;
  if (target.classList.contains("node")) {
    alert("node");
  }
});
```

```css
.node {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="nodes">
      <div class="node">
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="title">title <span class="subtitle">123</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="node">
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="title">title <span class="subtitle">456</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the closest ancestor element that has a specific class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119673/find-the-closest-ancestor-element-that-has-a-specific-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to know whether one of the parent element in your DOM structure is of **class** `node`, then you can make use of `closest(selector)`. In the following, we are changing the style of the node if it exists :-

```js
document.querySelector(".nodes").addEventListener("click", function (e) {

  var target = e.target;
  const node = target.closest(".node");
  if (node) {
    node.style.background = 'green';
  }
});
```

```css
.node {
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
}
.image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="nodes">
      <div class="node">
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="title">title <span class="subtitle">123</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="node">
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="title">title <span class="subtitle">456</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```