# Select the parent of the parent of an element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to select the parent of the parent of a child in Javascript without chaining the same method twice: child.parentElement.parentElement.Is there a method for this? The element I want to select is `parent1`.

The code is just to illustrate the problem, but all I want is to know if there is a method that can substitute the .parentElement.parentElement. I need to select it like this because my code is introduced dinamically into the page.

This is the code to illustrate the problem:

```js
const body = document.querySelector('body');

body.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.parentElement.parentElement.classList.toggle('black');
});
```

```css
.parent1 {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 20px;
}

.parent2 {
 background: blue;
 padding: 20px;
}

.black {
 background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent1">
  <div class="parent2">
    <button>Click</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('button')` is shorter. Same effect

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the closest ancestor element that has a specific class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119673/find-the-closest-ancestor-element-that-has-a-specific-class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to find the first parent element that matches a selector, in our case, `.parent1`:

```js
const body = document.querySelector('body');

body.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.closest('.parent1').classList.toggle('black');
});
```

```css
.parent1 {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 20px;
}

.parent2 {
 background: blue;
 padding: 20px;
}

.black {
 background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent1">
  <div class="parent2">
    <button>Click</button>
  </div>
</div>
```