# How to easily stop Facebook "ads" showing up in the feed by only using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, facebook, ads

When scrolling on Facebook feed, there are loads of "suggested" and "sponsored" posts... anyone could find a simple and neat way to stop them from showing up by only using JavaScript?

Here is a solution I came up with, feel free to use/modify and suggest any improvements, please! Thank you in advance.

```
/*
   When scrolling through the facebook feed, if the mouse will be over
   a sponsored or a suggested for you post, the post will be removed (hidden)
   from the HTML page.
   
   HOW TO USE:
   Log into facebook, open the console of the browser (developer tools) and
   copy and paste and run the below code. THEN, write adBlocker.start() and
   hit [ENTER] to start and adBlocker.stop() followed by [ENTER] to stop it.
*/

adBlocker = {}
adBlocker.toRemoveDivs = [];

// the direct descendant child <div> of the <div> having the
// attribute role="feed" is the main parent div for the href link
adBlocker.postsContainerDIV = document.querySelector('div[role="feed"]>div');

// from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119673/find-the-closest-ancestor-element-that-has-a-specific-class
adBlocker.findAncestor = function (el, sel) {
    while ((el = el.parentElement) && !((el.matches || el.matchesSelector).call(el,sel)));
    return el;
}

adBlocker.scanForSponsoredDivs = function() {
    document.querySelectorAll('a[aria-label="Sponsored"]')
        .forEach(
            aHrefElement => adBlocker.toRemoveDivs.push( adBlocker.findAncestor( aHrefElement, 'div[data-pagelet^="FeedUnit_"]' ) )
        )
}

adBlocker.scanForSuggestedDivs = function() {
    document.querySelectorAll('span.x193iq5w.xeuugli.x13faqbe.x1vvkbs.x10flsy6.x1lliihq.x1s928wv.xhkezso.x1gmr53x.x1cpjm7i.x1fgarty.x1943h6x.x4zkp8e.x41vudc.x6prxxf.xvq8zen.xo1l8bm.xi81zsa[dir="auto"]')
        .forEach( function( span ) {
            if (span.innerHTML === "Suggested for you")
                adBlocker.toRemoveDivs.push( adBlocker.findAncestor( span, 'div[data-pagelet^="FeedUnit_"]' ) )
        })
}

adBlocker.isItASuggestedDiv = function(div) {
    span = div.querySelectorAll('span.x193iq5w.xeuugli.x13faqbe.x1vvkbs.x10flsy6.x1lliihq.x1s928wv.xhkezso.x1gmr53x.x1cpjm7i.x1fgarty.x1943h6x.x4zkp8e.x41vudc.x6prxxf.xvq8zen.xo1l8bm.xi81zsa[dir="auto"]')[0];
    return (span && span.innerHTML && span.innerHTML==="Suggested for you");
}

adBlocker.isItASponsoredDiv = function(div) {
    aHref = div.querySelectorAll('a[aria-label="Sponsored"]')[0];
    return aHref ? true : false;
}

adBlocker.hide = function( div ) {
    if ( div && div.style ) div.style.display = "none";
}

adBlocker.removeDivs = function() {
    for (div of adBlocker.toRemoveDivs) {
        // remove sponsoredDiv div from the facebook feed
        // adBlocker.postsContainerDIV.removeChild( div ); // this would again trigger MutationObserver...
        // to avoid triggering mutationObserver, we just hide the DIV
        adBlocker.hide( div );
        
        // remove DIV from the array of toRemoveDivs
        index = adBlocker.toRemoveDivs.indexOf( div );
        adBlocker.toRemoveDivs.splice( index, 1 );
    }
}

adBlocker.searchAndRemoveDivs = function() {
  adBlocker.scanForSponsoredDivs();
  adBlocker.scanForSuggestedDivs();
  adBlocker.removeDivs();
}

// from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver
// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
adBlocker.observer_config = { childList: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
adBlocker.observerCallback = (mutationList, observer) => {
  for (mutation of mutationList) {
    if (mutation.addedNodes.length > 0) {
      for (div of mutation.addedNodes) {
        if ( adBlocker.isItASuggestedDiv( div ) ||
             adBlocker.isItASponsoredDiv( div ) )
            adBlocker.hide( div );
      }
    }
  }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
adBlocker.observer = new MutationObserver( adBlocker.observerCallback );

adBlocker.start = function() {
    console.log("adBlocker: Starting up...");
    
    // Since facebook has already loaded some posts into the feed,
    // remove any sponsored and suggested ones...
    console.log("adBlocker: Removing ads already loaded into your feed.");
    adBlocker.searchAndRemoveDivs();
    
    // Start observing the posts container for any changes, like,
    // if user scrolls and more posts are being loaded and further
    // remove any sponsored and suggested DIVs
    console.log("adBlocker: Setting up dynamic load observer for future ads.");
    adBlocker.observer.observe( adBlocker.postsContainerDIV, adBlocker.observer_config );
    console.log("adBlocker: All done, happy scrolling, ad free - no suggested for you and no sponsored posts either! :D");
}

adBlocker.stop = function() {
    adBlocker.observer.disconnect();
    console.log("adBlocker: Service NOW stopped! (use adBlocker.start() to restart it again)");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some time, there were some changes in the DOM of the facebook feed and it's posts and some "Suggested for you" and some "Sponsored" post made their way through the adBlocker javascript I originally came up with.

Further, more changes came in, with posts that had "Follow" in their headers and a different kind of Sponsored post that is now captured and filtered out as well. Facebook becomes more annoying with time, isn't it?

So, I have spent some more time looking at the changes and improved it to a better and simpler variant of the original. Feel free to use it! :) And give any improvement ideas!

PS: ON TOP OF EVERYTHING, Chromium & Brave browsers have introduced a console paste protection against Javascript being pasted into the console or, in other words, against self-XSS; on the security side, this is awesome, however, for the more adventurous developers and for those who like to hack stuff around, it is a bit of a pain. The solution to this is to disable the Console setting as portrayed in screenshot from [pasteboard.co](https://pasteboard.co/Q1rk3pHnGNEG.png) (every time a browser is restarted, as the setting is not persisted nor saved).

```js
/*
   Version 2.2
   Suggested div extended to include "Follow" too.
   Sponsored div now captures a 2nd variant as well.
   
   When scrolling through the facebook feed, if the mouse will be over
   a sponsored or a suggested for you post, the post will be removed (hidden)
   from the HTML page.
   
   HOW TO USE:
   Log into facebook, open the console of the browser (developer tools) and
   copy and paste and run the below code. THEN, write adBlocker.run() and
   hit [ENTER] to start and adBlocker.stop() followed by [ENTER] to stop it.
*/

adBlocker = {}
adBlocker.isRunning = false;

// the direct descendant child <div> of the <div> having the
// attribute role="feed" is the main parent div for the href link
adBlocker.postsContainerDIV = document.querySelector('div[role="feed"]>div');

adBlocker.hide = function( div ) {
    if ( div && div.style ) div.style.display = "none";
}

adBlocker.isItAFacebookSuggestedDiv = function(div) {
    allChildSpans = div.querySelectorAll("span");
    if (allChildSpans.length > 0) {
        let i = 0;
        while ( i<allChildSpans.length ) {
            if ( allChildSpans[i].innerHTML==="Suggested for you" ) return true;
            if ( allChildSpans[i].innerHTML==="Follow" ) return true;
            i++;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

adBlocker.isItASponsoredDivV1 = function(div) {
    aHref = div.querySelectorAll('a[aria-label="Sponsored"]')[0];
    return aHref ? true : false;
}

adBlocker.isItASponsoredDivV2 = function(div) {
    let SPANsWithID = div.querySelectorAll("span[id]");
    if (SPANsWithID.length === 0) return false;
    let testDIVs = SPANsWithID[0].querySelectorAll("div");
    if (testDIVs.length > 0) {
        let i = 0;
        while ( i<testDIVs.length )
            if ( testDIVs[i++].innerHTML.contains("Sponsored") ) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

adBlocker.isItASponsoredDiv = function(div) {
    return adBlocker.isItASponsoredDivV1(div) || adBlocker.isItASponsoredDivV2(div);
}

adBlocker.if_is_ad_div_hide_it = function( div ) {
    if ( adBlocker.isItAFacebookSuggestedDiv( div ) ||
         adBlocker.isItASponsoredDiv( div ) )
        adBlocker.hide( div );
}

adBlocker.hideAlreadyLoadedUnwantedDivs = function() {
    // all already loaded posts (DIVs)
    allPostDivs = adBlocker.postsContainerDIV.querySelectorAll('div[data-pagelet^="FeedUnit_"]');
    
    if (allPostDivs.length > 0) {
        var i = 0;
        while ( i<allPostDivs.length )
            adBlocker.if_is_ad_div_hide_it( allPostDivs[i++] );
    }
}

// from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver
// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
adBlocker.observer_config = { childList: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
adBlocker.observerCallback = (mutationList, observer) => {
  for (mutation of mutationList) {
    if (mutation.addedNodes.length > 0)
      for (div of mutation.addedNodes)
        adBlocker.if_is_ad_div_hide_it( div );
  }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
adBlocker.observer = new MutationObserver( adBlocker.observerCallback );

adBlocker.run = function() {
    if ( adBlocker.isRunning ) {
        console.log("adBlocker: is already running...");
        return;
    }
    console.log("adBlocker: Starting up...");
    // Since facebook has already loaded some posts into the feed,
    // remove any sponsored and suggested ones...
    console.log("adBlocker: Removing ads already loaded into your feed.");
    adBlocker.hideAlreadyLoadedUnwantedDivs(); //adBlocker.searchAndRemoveDivs();
    
    // Start observing the posts container for any changes, like,
    // if user scrolls and more posts are being loaded and further
    // remove any sponsored and suggested DIVs
    console.log("adBlocker: Setting up dynamic load observer for future ads.");
    adBlocker.observer.observe( adBlocker.postsContainerDIV, adBlocker.observer_config );
    console.log("adBlocker: All done, happy scrolling, ad free - no suggested for you and no sponsored posts either! :D");
    adBlocker.isRunning = true;
}

adBlocker.stop = function() {
    if ( !adBlocker.isRunning ) {
        console.log("adBlocker: is not running...");
        return;
    }
    adBlocker.observer.disconnect();
    console.log("adBlocker: Service NOW stopped! (use adBlocker.start() to restart it again)");
    adBlocker.isRunning = false;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).