# Change div content by clicking on a button - without jQuery, please

Tags: javascript, html

There is an `i` button in the middle of my website. I'd ask you to click it—you would see a button—`contact`.

When the user clicks on it, I want the content of the `div` above to be changed.

#### This is the code:

```
<section id="about" class="wrapper about accelerate hide">
            <div class="cell accelerate">
                <div class="cables center accelerate">
                    <div class="panel accelerate">
                        <header>
                        <h1>gog<em>sem</em>cel</h1>
                        </header>
                        <p><strong>gogsemcel </strong>is a trademark of <i font-family="Trebuchet MS">Company</i>.</p>
                        <p>This project is a collaboration between<br><a href="mailto:coming@soon.no" target="_blank">Company name</a> &amp; <a href="" target="_blank">gogsemcels</a>.</p>
                        <ul class="links">
                            <li><a class="download" href="info/info.html">More Info</a></li>
                            <li><a class="github" target="_blank" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

The button's `class` is `github`.
Any suggestions?

Gigantic thanks.

Comment: Cn you use jQuery or MooTools? or just "pure" javascript? and what would you like to change the content to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have jQuery on your page so you could use this:

```
$('#about a.github').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var content = $(this).closest('.panel').find('p');
    content[0].innerHTML = 'This is a new text!'
    content[1].innerHTML = 'This is the second line!'
});
```

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8sd6v/)

I am not a fan of disabling right-click. Just FYI I can see the whole content anyway...

If you want to do it with vanilla JS you can use this (credits do [Chris's nice function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14234618/2256325)):

```
function collectionHas(a, b) { //helper function (see below)
    for (var i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (a[i] == b) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function findParentBySelector(elm, selector) {
    var all = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    var cur = elm.parentNode;
    while (cur && !collectionHas(all, cur)) { //keep going up until you find a match
        cur = cur.parentNode; //go up
    }
    return cur; //will return null if not found
}
var git = document.querySelector('#about a.github');
git.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var content = findParentBySelector(git, '.panel').querySelectorAll('p');
    content[0].innerHTML = 'This is a new text!'
    content[1].innerHTML = 'This is the second line!'
});
```

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/enk6K/)

Comment: Umm/// do you know any way to do it without jQuery? There are some contradictions

Comment: @user3556445, I see you are loading jQUery on your page, but if you do not want jQuery try my updated version with vanilla JS. And btw, if this answer was usefull, welcome to vote it up.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `href` attribute to `Contact` link.

```
<a class="github" target="_blank" href="#contact">Contact</a>
```

Then, add `id` attribute to 2 `p` elements for easily selecting.

```
<section id="about" class="wrapper about accelerate hide">
   <div class="cell accelerate">
      <div class="cables center accelerate">
         <div class="panel accelerate">
            <header>
               <h1>viva<em>stem</em>cell</h1>
            </header>
            <p id="abc"><strong>vivastemcell </strong>is a trademark of <i font-family="Trebuchet MS">Tsovn Tsirani Company</i>.</p>
            <p id="def">This project is a collaboration between<br><a href="mailto:coming@soon.no" target="_blank">Tsovn Tsirani</a> &amp; <a href="" target="_blank">vivastemcells</a>.</p>
            <ul class="links">
               <li><a class="download" href="info/info.html">More Info</a></li>
               <li><a class="github" target="_blank" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Now, in `onload` event of your page, add following code. This use pure Javascript that you want.

```
// You can use document.querySelector -> returns the first element found.
var gh = document.querySelectorAll('#about .github')[0];

if (gh) {
    gh.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('abc').textContent = new Date().getTime();
        document.getElementById('def').textContent = new Date().getTime();
    })
}
```