# How to delete a div element if there's a specific class inside?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="class1">
   Parent element
   <span class="class2">Child element</span>
</div>
```

If 'class2' exists under 'class1', then I want to delete 'class1'. How could I do that?

Comment: Explain more! Do you want to delete `.class1` div or `.class2` div?

Comment: i wanna delete .class1 if class2 found in , u got me ?

Comment: @Amir direct children or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: How to get parent element by selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14234560/javascript-how-to-get-parent-element-by-selector)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you are using jQuery**

```
$('.class1').each(function() { // Loop through all 'class1'
   if($('.class2', this).length) // If class1 contains 'class2'
      $(this).remove(); // Delete it!
});
```

**If you are using pure Javascript**

```
document.querySelectorAll('.class1').forEach(function(element) {
   if(element.querySelector('.class2') !== null) {
      element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
   }
});
```

Working demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/d6r6p68k/

Comment: Note, Question does not have `jquery` tag.

Comment: You can use `$('.class1:has(.class2)')` instead of `.each()`.

Comment: Added pure javascript version