# React - How to get parent attribute value in select drop down

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<ul>
    {
        this.state.pics ? this.state.pics.map((pic, index) => {
            return (
                <li key={index}>
                    <img src={pic.url} height="200" alt="Image preview..." />
                    <select data-id={index} onChange={this.setValue}>
                        <option value="1" >Monday</option>
                        <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
                        <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
                        <option value="4">Thursday</option>
                        <option value="4">Friday</option>
                        <option value="4">Saturday</option>
                        <option value="4">Sunday</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
            )
        }) : ""
    }
</ul>
```

On every change, I would like to get the value of data-id attribute which is nothing but value of index . or is there a way to directly access the value of key attribute of li . I am using react . Also is it a good practice in react to directly access the dom by query selector

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: How to get parent element by selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14234560/javascript-how-to-get-parent-element-by-selector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from  pure JS based solutions of accessing the DOM via event APIs (in your case), you can also use the [Refs feature of React](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

But as the docs themselves say

> Avoid using refs for anything that can be done declaratively.

In your case, accessing the select element's custom attributes are pretty straightforward

1. Create a ref to the element you wish to access the DOM
2. Assign it to a variable which is accessible in your event callback
3. Access the variable ,which has the DOM reference in your function.

   `<select
     ref={select => (this.selectElement = select)}
     data-id={1}
     onChange={this.setValue}>`

A sample can be found here in the [CodeSandox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/lrj0nppx2z)

And to answer your other question "Also is it a good practice in react to directly access the dom by query selector" - I'd say use that as a last resort , most of the problems can be solved by moving around props and states in component heirarchy.

Recommended reading

1. [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)
2. [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
const setValue = (e) => {
 console.log(e.target.getAttribute('data-id'))
}
```

The onChange callback gets the normal javascript event object which can be used to access the attribute you want.

Answer (score -2):

You could try something like this `$(this).parent().attr('data-id');`

Comment: i am using react . is this a good pratcice to acces dom directly

Comment: downvoting because the OP is asking about react and the solution provided is jquery.